# Optimizing a Site for Blackberry Curve (Maintaining same in iOS/Android)

Tags: html, css, blackberry, mobile, meta-tags

I've created a mobile version of a website - simple Table HTML and scarce CSS. Renders great in iOS and Android, I've even used a Meta Width Set to take the width across devices. So, it even renders great in Black Berry width wise-

But, I came across a huge problem - **The site, for some odd reason on Blackberry - requires a Zoom (Though not needed) before being able to access a link or read the text**. I understand Blackberry res is about 480px - and iOS 900 something, right? Any suggestions on keeping the width to take across iOS, Android, and Blackberry - while not forcing the user to Zoom (With that Magnifying Zoom Icon) on Blackberry? Is this a Javascript thing, a (Hopefully not) PHP/Server side thing?

**Ultimately, how do I create a Mobile version of a site - that maintains rendering well in iOS, Android, but also in BB without making the user 'Zoom > Click > Content' but just to browse it normally, 'Click > Content'. But also doesn't require me reducing the size it'll display in iOS/Android?**

The way this website is setup is the ultimate goal; http://lisaunger.mobi/ It renders everywhere and exactly like I'm trying to render mine - not sure how, though.

Please throw me any suggestions as I'll be testing them all tomorrow.

**Blackberry is: Curve 8520 v4.6.1.259 2009**

Here's the code I have at the moment:

*Markup:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN"
"http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">



<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="mobilesub.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div style="width: 480px;margin: auto;">
<div>

  <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" border="0"/></a>
  <br />

</div>


    <div>

    <a href="books.html"><img src="mobile buttons/books_off.png"   border=0  /></a>

    </div>

    <div>


     <a href="news.html"><img src="mobile buttons/news_off.png"  border=0  /></a>

     </div>

     <div>

     <a href="app.html"><img src="mobile buttons/app_off.png"  border=0 /></a>

     </div>

     <div>

      <a href="about.html"><img src="mobile buttons/about_off.png"  border=0  /></a>

     </div>

     <div>

     <a href="videos.html"><img src="mobile buttons/videos_off.png" border=0  /></a>

     </div>

     <div>


    About

 <br />  

The New York Times bestseller

Contact




</div>

     <div>
     </div>
     </div>

</body>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://m.link.me/tracker.js"></script>
</html>

<script type="application/x-javascript">
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
addEventListener("load", function() {
setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
    }, false);
    }

    function hideURLbar() {
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }

</script>
```

*CSS*

```
body {

padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;    
background-color:#000;
width: 100%;
text-align: center; 
color: #fff;

}

.center-display {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#content {

}


#h6 {

font-size: 26px;

}

div {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**Update:** *Setting the site to 320px in width, and adding the meta-initial scale allows the zoom to go away and renders the way it should in Blackberry - but ends up taking a way from iOS and Android a little - as now the site zooms passed the browser width in those devices causing a little bit of a horizontal scroll - so close!*

Comment: you should specify the OS version of your Curve; OS 6 and 7 have good browsers, older ones are famously bogus

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what OS it is; but is Curve 8250

Comment: I think this is it; v4.6.1.259

Comment: you can never make that ancient device compatible with ios and android

Comment: It's not that old; it was 2009 - and I've seen websites that are compatible across using '320 and up boilerplate' and CSS media queries - I guess this is going to be my solution for next time - cheers for the response!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to define the website by devices - so if i will go on the web with my bb it will be smaller in that case so the user wont need to do zoom 
[this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/03/how-to-build-a-mobile-website/) might help

Comment: The width is taking just fine with Meta Tags I've set - but no matter what the width is, how perfect it fits or doesn't - it still requires the 'Zoom Click > Content' before being able to click links. Even if it just zooms in 1-3px it forces the user to do it.

Comment: what about - `<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />`

Comment: I wasn't able to try that one; the support to remove the 'zoom' was cut off and next time I'm just going to design responsively with CSS media queries. I'm assuming this would the best solution -